# pdo insert getting \ in the url

Tags: php, pdo, sql-insert, backslash

I am trying to insert html by tinymce.

For example:

```
<img title="q" src="../kcfinder/upload/image/3b5330574c883fe1040eaddeb596ea20.jpg" alt="q" width="640" height="480" />
```

the PDO makes this

```
<img title=\"q\" src=\"../../../kcfinder/upload/image/3b5330574c883fe1040eaddeb596ea20.jpg\" alt=\"q\" width=\"640\" height=\"480\" />
```

this is the insertAction:

```
    $data = array_slice($data1, 0, -1);
    foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
        $ins[] = ':' . $column;
    } 
    $ins = implode(',', $ins);
    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($data));
    $sql = "insert into $this->tableName ($fields) values ($ins)";
    $sth = $this->connection->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($data as $f => $v) {
        $sth->bindValue(':' . $f, $v);
    }
    return $sth->execute();
```

I tried the str_replace, but that doesnt work.
Someone an idea how to remove the \ ?

Solution:

```
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
 $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
 while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
        unset($process[$key][$k]);
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
            $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
        } else {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
        }
    }
}
unset($process);
}
```

Comment: Your code is likely vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: i know, strip_tags and trim you mean?

Comment: neither of them adds slashes

Comment: @YourCommonSense  i thought that prepared statements with bindValue were enough?

Comment: @STT LCU Yes thats correct

Comment: @STTLCU `($fields)` <-- I don't see no prepared statement here. Do you?

Comment: Nope, thnks for the input!

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Those backslashes don't get there by themselves; do you have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled in your `php.ini`?

Comment: @jack, yes i have, i dont have access, my hosting has to do that

Comment: As a first step you may want to `array_map('stripslashes', $_POST)` if `magic_quotes_gpc()` yields `true`. For the rest, check YCS's answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense yeah that "prepare" caught me, my bad.

Comment: @Jack, do you mean the $fields preparing?

Comment: @Bas refer to [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) (at the bottom) - there is a safer solution for your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not PDO but some your own code.

It's either [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) of some sort of "sanitizing" function. You have to get rid of either of them.